# Civimail delivering AND bouncing at the same time - what's missing?

Tags: civimail, email, bounce

I could use some help troubleshooting Civimail- I seem to have bounce processing working correctly except when a mailing goes out, all recipients bounce AND all recipients receive the email.

Any suggestions for where to start looking?

Using ()mail to send, and a return@domain.org google apps account for bounces.

Comment: More info:

It looks like the mailing is being directed back to my smtp server, even though we're set to use google apps. 

Any thoughts?

Hi. This is the qmail-send program at mainecancer.org.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<smtp@mainecancer.org>:
74.125.22.27 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out finally: bad default setting in php.ini.

The isp had this param added by default: mail.force_extra_parameters adding "SMTP = smtp.myisp.net" to every outgoing mail sent by mail().

This caused every email to bounce when civi called qmail.

Sheesh. I want those two days back.